# Microsoft Security Essentials Definitions not Updating neither Manually nor Automatically

Tags: windows-7, ms-security-essentials, av-definitions

I learnt last year that Microsoft will be discontinuing support for windows 7 soon, and also from (I think) November that definitions will be having the SHA3 signing for security purposes and as a result of that any low version of Windows without the necessary files/drivers to decrypt it (i.e Windows 7 SP1 or lower, Vista, XP) wont be able to use it. And true to their words its not updating since December. the Solution I mostly see on their site is to update windows but most of the updates are failing. am hoping there is a library i could install that will complement for the needed SHA3 key since Windows 8 up till 10 are doing fine with the definition but lower windows are seriously not feeling fine with it.

Comment: You can download the latest MSE definitions from this link, then install them>>>>>https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/971606/how-to-manually-download-the-latest-definition-updates-for-microsoft-s

Comment: They appear to work in XP also, as stated on that page in step 3.

Comment: Yes @Moab
I have downloaded the definitions, But not updating,

Comment: We need more details on "not updating"

Comment: Ok, what I meant was, normally after downloading a definition. I open it and automatically the Antivirus definitions will be updated, but now it just runs and after some minutes terminates (I know because I tracked it from the Task Manager) However this is normal, because after that the Antivirus definitions should be automatically Updated, but this time around it runs and terminates but the definition is not updated.

Answer (score 0):

Up to date Windows 7 Pro is downloading and installing Security Essentials as of today (March 2020), but Vista and XP have not been able to successfully update Security Essentials automatically or pressing the update button for some time (a year or so ago, plus or minus).

I expect Windows 7 will stop updating at some point - likely less than a year from now.

The older systems are a security risk and that situation is getting worse.

Comment: I haven't noted the Windows 7 edition, however the one in question is ultimate. 

And Yes I think general updates will also close soon for windows 7. that's why am hoping if there are any specific update that will solve this issue so I can source for and keep them also for future reference. 

Because I honestly prefer W7 to all the other Windows

Comment: My Windows 7 Pro machine keeps updating - I do not know for how long. But older machines - not for me at all.